# HighCharts getting data from database to outside js file

Tags: javascript, highcharts, asp-classic

I'm trying to populate a HighCharts with results from SQL Server in Classic ASP. 
As long as the js is in the asp file the code is working, assume n11=2 ie.

```
<script>
$(function () {

var N = '<% = n11 %>'
var brcolor = []
var tl = []
var frcolor = []
var rd = []
var inrd = []
var otrd = []
var gg = []
var zeva = []
var ovi = []

brcolor[1] = '#666666'
brcolor[2] = '#666666'

tl[1] = 'name1'
tl[2] = 'name2'

frcolor[1] = '#666666'
frcolor[2] = '#666666'

rd[1] = '109%'
rd[2] = '96%'

inrd[1] = '112%'
inrd[2] = '106%'

otrd[1] = '99%'
otrd[2] = '93%'

gg[1] = 80
gg[2] = 65

zeva[1] = '#eeeeee'
zeva[2] = '#eeeeee'
zeva[3] = '#ffffff'

ovi[1] = 1
ovi[2] = 1
ovi[3] = 0


if (!Highcharts.theme) {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        chart: {
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.002)'
        },
        colors: ['#666666', '#666666', '#666666', '#666666', '#666666', '#666666', '#666666'],

        tooltip: {
            style: {
                color: '#a0a0a0'
            }
        }
    });
}


Highcharts.chart('11', {

    chart: {
        type: 'solidgauge',
        margin: [0, 0, 0, 0]

    },

    title: {
        text: '',
        style: {
            fontSize: '12px'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        shadow: false,
        useHTML: true,
        style: {
            fontSize: '14px',
            fontFamily: 'arial',
            direction: 'rtl'
        },
        pointFormat: '<div style="width: 120px; white-space:normal; text-align: right">{series.name}</div><div style="text-align: center"><span style="font-size:1.3em; font-weight: bold; color: {point.color}; ">{point.y}%</span></div>'
        // positioner: function (labelWidth, labelHeight) {
        //   return {
        //     x: 120 - labelWidth / 2,
        //      y: 20
        //  };
        // }
    },

    pane: {
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 360,


        background: [{
            outerRadius: '112%',
            innerRadius: '106%',

            backgroundColor: zeva[1],
            borderWidth: ovi[1]
        }, {
            outerRadius: '99%',
            innerRadius: '93%',

            backgroundColor: zeva[2],
            borderWidth: ovi[2]
        }, {
            outerRadius: '86%',
            innerRadius: '80%',

            backgroundColor: zeva[3],
            borderWidth: ovi[3]

        }]

    },

    yAxis: {

        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        lineWidth: 0,
        tickPositions: []
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    plotOptions: {
        solidgauge: {
            borderWidth: '6px',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            linecap: 'round',
            stickyTracking: false
        }
    },

    series: []
});






var newSeries = []
for (var i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    var newData = [];
    var seria = {};
    var datai = {};
    datai['color'] = frcolor[i];
    datai['radius'] = rd[i];
    datai['innerRadius'] = rd[i];
    datai['y'] = gg[i];

    seria['borderColor'] = brcolor[i];
    seria['name'] = tl[i];
    seria['data'] = [datai];

    newSeries.push(seria);

}

var chart = $('#11').highcharts();

$.each(newSeries, function (i, ns) {
    chart.addSeries(ns, false);
});
chart.redraw();

});

    </script>
```

But when I have a separate js file (11.js) and includ it in the file head it does not work.

The head line

```
<script type=text/javascript src=charts/11.js></script>
```

The js is:

```
$(function () {

var N = '<% = n11 %>'
var brcolor = []
var tl = []
var frcolor = []
var rd = []
var inrd = []
var otrd = []
var gg = []
var zeva = []
var ovi = []

brcolor[1] = '#666666'
brcolor[2] = '#666666'

tl[1] = 'name1'
tl[2] = 'name2'

frcolor[1] = '#666666'
frcolor[2] = '#666666'

rd[1] = '109%'
rd[2] = '96%'

inrd[1] = '112%'
inrd[2] = '106%'

otrd[1] = '99%'
otrd[2] = '93%'

gg[1] = 80
gg[2] = 65

zeva[1] = '#eeeeee'
zeva[2] = '#eeeeee'
zeva[3] = '#ffffff'

ovi[1] = 1
ovi[2] = 1
ovi[3] = 0


if (!Highcharts.theme) {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        chart: {
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.002)'
        },
        colors: ['#666666', '#666666', '#666666', '#666666', '#666666', '#666666', '#666666'],

        tooltip: {
            style: {
                color: '#a0a0a0'
            }
        }
    });
}


Highcharts.chart('11', {

    chart: {
        type: 'solidgauge',
        margin: [0, 0, 0, 0]

    },

    title: {
        text: '',
        style: {
            fontSize: '12px'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        shadow: false,
        useHTML: true,
        style: {
            fontSize: '14px',
            fontFamily: 'arial',
            direction: 'rtl'
        },
        pointFormat: '<div style="width: 120px; white-space:normal; text-align: right">{series.name}</div><div style="text-align: center"><span style="font-size:1.3em; font-weight: bold; color: {point.color}; ">{point.y}%</span></div>'
        // positioner: function (labelWidth, labelHeight) {
        //   return {
        //     x: 120 - labelWidth / 2,
        //      y: 20
        //  };
        // }
    },

    pane: {
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 360,


        background: [{
            outerRadius: '112%',
            innerRadius: '106%',

            backgroundColor: zeva[1],
            borderWidth: ovi[1]
        }, {
            outerRadius: '99%',
            innerRadius: '93%',

            backgroundColor: zeva[2],
            borderWidth: ovi[2]
        }, {
            outerRadius: '86%',
            innerRadius: '80%',

            backgroundColor: zeva[3],
            borderWidth: ovi[3]

        }]

    },

    yAxis: {

        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        lineWidth: 0,
        tickPositions: []
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    plotOptions: {
        solidgauge: {
            borderWidth: '6px',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            linecap: 'round',
            stickyTracking: false
        }
    },

    series: []
});






var newSeries = []
for (var i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    var newData = [];
    var seria = {};
    var datai = {};
    datai['color'] = frcolor[i];
    datai['radius'] = rd[i];
    datai['innerRadius'] = rd[i];
    datai['y'] = gg[i];

    seria['borderColor'] = brcolor[i];
    seria['name'] = tl[i];
    seria['data'] = [datai];

    newSeries.push(seria);

}

var chart = $('#11').highcharts();

$.each(newSeries, function (i, ns) {
    chart.addSeries(ns, false);
});
chart.redraw();
```

});

If I'm doing the same but putting a number instead of '<% = n11 %>' it is Ok too.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889815/can-i-write-asp-code-in-a-js-file may be related

Comment: The issue there is different. thank you apokryfos

Comment: How can you be sure? It seems like ASP is not being interpreted in .js files

Comment: As I can see it the first answer there deals with code in the same file. And the second with non classic asp

Comment: Try renaming `charts/11.js` to `charts/11.asp` and use `<script type="text/javascript" src="charts/11.asp"></script>` and check if it works.

Comment: @KacperMadej can you advise?

Comment: renaming charts/11.js to charts/11.asp and use <script type="text/javascript" src="charts/11.asp"></script> did not work. thank you

Comment: You could add console.log(N) after N is defined and it's value is set in JS file to check if ASP code is executed. See in browser console (Developer Tools) the N value from console.log(N). If it is not set, then ASP code is not executed.

Comment: But why it should be different if I write the javascript code  in the asp file or include js file to the asp file ?

Comment: ASP runs on the server side. The server, by default, chooses to only run ASP code if it's contained in `.asp` files, unless you configure it otherwise., which is what my original comment was indicating.

Comment: I understood the reason you suggested to change the js extention to asp, but it still did not work

Comment: I am not an ASP expert, I can't help you with it.

Comment: @apokryfos I'm trying to get your suggestion work, do I need to make any other changes in the 11.asp file except changing it's extention?

Comment: It's suggested to also add `<% Response.ContentType = "text/javascript" %>` at the top of the script. Also make sure your `<script type="text/javascript" src="charts/11.asp"></script>` has the "quotes" around the `type` and `src`

Comment: It works with <!-- #include file="charts/11.asp" --> or <!-- #include file="charts/11.js" --> but now instead of html text that are in Hebrew  I got odd signs I'm using <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255">
and before it works correctly

Comment: Charset being windows-1255 is not typical. Make sure it matches your file's charset (or try charset=UTF-8 if in doubt)

Comment: windows-1255 is typical for Hebrew

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to know how to access your data from an external JavaScript file.

[Here is a plnkr using requirejs to achieve this.](https://embed.plnkr.co/sduT6ubBBkFtqMG6SFrQ/)

Additionally, you mentioned that when you change <% = n11 %> to a number then it's also ok. The reason for this is that you are accessing N in a loop, and then evaluating N against i. But <% = n11 %> doesn't evaluate to a number, so the loop doesn't work unless you change it to a number, then it will loop that many times.

In the demo I've changed it to 2, because that's the average length of your data arrays.

Also, since you want to create gauges, and they typically don't have multiple sets of data, I thought maybe you wanted multiple gauges, so I modified the demo provided in the [solidgauge api documentation on highcharts](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.solidgauge).

Comment: Sorry @ejane but you are so wrong and misleading. The function is working perfectly if it is in the main asp file, all the problems and questions are because I'm trying to have the function in a separate file. Please note I'm using the activity gauge that can have multiple sets of data http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-activity